# I am getting an error, 'Permission denied', port = 0x3903, name = 'org.vim.MacVim.ServiceProvider', from VIM. How do I fix it

Tags: macos, macvim

I am on a mac 10.5 and I am running MacVim 7.3.  I get this error.  What is the meaning of this error?
How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is logged because you are running two different versions of MacVim at the same time, see:
http://code.google.com/p/macvim/issues/detail?id=180